# PHP + jQuery - How to form submit, process and redirect on success?

Tags: php, jquery

Stupid question (I seem to be leading all my questions with this phrase), but I was wondering if anyone out there had an elegant solution for processing forms via php and jquery and then redirects

> **[HTML FORM]** --> *submits via jquery post to* --> **[PHP FILE]** -->
>   *upon success redirects to* --> **[SUCCESS HTML PAGE]**  *(and if not success returns back to [HTML FORM]*

**HTML FORM example**

```
<form action="procRegister.php" method ="post" id="registerAccount" name="registerAccount">
...fields here ladeeda...
</form>
```

**JQUERY POST example**

```
$("form#registerAccount").submit(function(){
    $.post(
        "procRegister.php",
        $("form#registerAccount").serialize(),
        function(data){alert(data.msg);}, 
        'json'
           );   
    return false;
});
```

**PHP PROCESSING example**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $return['msg'] = 'Alright!';
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

If everything works correctly then the page would pop up an alert box saying "Alright!". Now, how and where would I implement the redirect upon success? i.e. Instead of sending "Alright" how would I redirect the user to, say a CONFIRMATION page?

Comment: Just a quick side-question - any reason why you don't just use the old, basic, traditional way of handling form submissions? Makes it alot simpler to redirect to a Success Page if all is good, or to return to the Form Page in the event of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just redirect the user to the success/failure page in javascript?

```
window.location = <url>
```

If you need some sort of token to access your success page you could possibly pass the URL  back in the JSON that is returned by your procRegister.php page:

```
function(data) {
    if (data.validated) { 
        window.location = data.successURL; 
    } else { 
        window.location = data.failureURL; 
    }
}
```

Comment: is this affected if javascript is turned off?